# How to pin a div in top of other div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i am trying to make the grey div covered by the white div, in other word, i wan the white div be the top layer in my page, not like this screenshot

[image]

i am using Bootstrap 4 in this layout

```css
.form-login {
    text-align: center;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.biside-form-login {
    text-align: left;
    background: #cecece;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-4 form-login">
         this is the white div
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 biside-form-login">
              this is the grey
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add a `z-index` to the white div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use 'z-index' like this

```css
.form-login {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    z-index:999;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [z-index](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/#:~:text=The%20z%2Dindex%20property%20in,than%20static%20(the%20default).)  in the white div

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative;` and `z-index: 999;` to the `form-login` `div`:

```
.form-login {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/MWjNLxx?editors=1100